# API Gateway sign request with AWS SDK for .NET

Tags: .net, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I have an API in API Gateway whose Authorization type I have set to AWS_IAM to have API Gateway verify the signature on requests.

And restrict the API endpoint to only specific IAM users.

Now the problem is how can I consume this API from .NET? I cannot create/compute the signature by myself. Does the AWS SDK for .NET offer any helper or utility method/class to have the signature computed which I can attach as the HTTP header to my HTTP request?

Or can the API Gateway SDK for .NET make signed requests to my restricted API Gateway endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Gateway doesn't yet support generated SDKs for .NET, so at this time your options are limited to:

1. Find a SigV4 signer library for .NET
2. Write your own SigV4 signer based on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html
3. Try to leverage the existing signing code in the AWS SDK for .NET
   http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-net/

Comment: Are there any SigV4 signing libraries available for .NET? Can you point me to any?

Comment: A just did a quick search and couldn't find anything that stands out. Your best bet may be to try 2 or 3. I will follow up internally to see if there's anything we can do to help.

Comment: Please let me know once you follow up with the team. Thanks.

Comment: how about javascript? Can we use IAM user using js sdk for api gateway?  without cognito? how to hide the keys on a client side web app?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a NuGet package called [AwsSignatureVersion4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AwsSignatureVersion4/) which has been verified to work with the AWS API Gateway. Would love to hear what you think of it!

Comment: Worked first time. Nice one!